# How do I force Gnome Web web browser to use a different config/cache directory?

Tags: linux, path

Gnome Web is the only application that I've seen that needs to create a `~/.var` directory, specifically:

```
~/.var/app/org.gnome.Epiphany/
```

I already have a .config, .local, .mozilla and more.
How can I force it to use something like ~/.config/ ?

Add to that, can I force Firefox to put it's .mozille in ~/.config/ ?

Comment: you could simply link the folder from one of the above mentioned folders but I don't think that is what you are asking but that answers the question as asked.

Answer (score 1):

> I already have a .config, .local, .mozilla and more. How can I force it to use something like ~/.config/ ?

Use the system-installed `epiphany` package instead of the Flatpak one.

`~/.var/` is created by the Flatpak runtime, exclusively for use by sandboxed apps.

Answer (score 0):

Extending user1686's answer:
This isn't really Epiphany's fault. This is how Flatpak works. The short answer is install the "native" epiphany and delete the dir.

The long answer is, assuming you are unwilling to lose any browser-associated data like cookies, this:

You probably might want to try and move the .var thing somewhere (e. g. `~/.config/flatpak/.var`), edit the environment to make Flatpak use the parent directory of .var (flatpak in this case) by setting `FLATPAK_USER_DIR` to the required path, and symlink or even hardlink (hardlink is better because no link icons in GUI and better performance) the home folders there to make it still have access to that.